# Python - Why does this make 8 recursive calls?

Tags: python

Currently reviewing for an upcoming exam, and was given this practice question, the answer is 8, but I am not sure why. Can someone break it down for me? I've tried tracing it, but it got **confusing** quick hehe.

```
def confuse(s):     
   if len(s) <= 1:        
      return s     
   x = len(s) // 2     
   return confuse(s[:x]) + confuse(s[x:]) 

print(confuse('annoy'))
```

Question: Excluding the call to confuse('annoy'), how many recursive calls are made before this function terminates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should draw this as a tree:

confuse('annoy'):

```
+- 'an' (half of annoy, rounded down)
|  +- 'a'
|  \- 'n'
\- 'noy'
   +- 'n'
   \- 'oy'
      +- 'o'
      \- 'y'
```

There's your eight calls.

Comment: Perhaps someone with better ascii art skills or a visual editor of some sort can make this more beautiful.

Comment: I realized I'm stupid, I made a careless mistake. Now I see how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They are called like this:

```
confuse('annoy')
confuse('an') + confuse('noy')  # 5//2 = 2
confuse('a') + confuse('n') # 2//2 = 1
confuse('n') + confuse('oy') # 3//2 = 1
confuse('o') + confuse('y') # 2//2 = 1
```

Therefore, 8.

Answer (score 3):

```
confuse('annoy') == confuse('an') + confuse('noy')
                 == confuse('a') + confuse('n') + confuse('n') + confuse('oy')
                 == 'a' + 'n' + 'n' + confuse('o') + confuse('y')
                 == 'a' + 'n' + 'n' + 'o' _ 'y'
                 == 'annoy'
```

Count the calls to `confuse` on the RHS, and you'll find 8 of them. Roughly speaking, you get `2**O(lg(n))` recursive calls for an input of length `n`.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the code to

```
def confuse(s):
   print("called with -->", s)
   if len(s) <= 1:        
      return s     
   x = len(s) // 2     
   return confuse(s[:x]) + confuse(s[x:]) 

confuse('annoy')
```

you will get

```
called with --> annoy
called with --> an
called with --> a
called with --> n
called with --> noy
called with --> n
called with --> oy
called with --> o
called with --> y
```

Excluding the call to confuse('annoy'), how many recursive calls are made before this function terminates? **9 - 1 = 8**

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help you to understand

```
def confuse(s):     
   if len(s) <= 1:        
      return s     
   x = len(s) // 2
   print(s[:x], s[x:])
   return confuse(s[:x]) + confuse(s[x:]) 

print(confuse('annoy'))
```